# Can we restrict user to search only those publication to which he has access?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are facing the problem with the search functionality in SDL Tridion 2011. We have created a user with access to only two publication, But user is able to search content in all publications and able to open component in read only mode. Do we have any way to restrict the user to search only those publication in which he has access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content in question is in a parent publication, and the editor has READ access to the items in question in a child publication, then this is expected.

If the content is in another blueprint branch and it is not inherited to the publications that the editor has access to, then it shouldn't show up in the search results.

N

Comment: I believe this is how it is working with Tridion 2011 GA(known defect? Not sure). Even if the item is not in blueprint hierarchy, when you search "All Publications" scope results will show up from all publication regardless of the BP context. Haven't checked with SP1.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue on Service Pack 1 (HR1). If I search with an Admin and with a user with access to only one publication I get different results, all search results for the user are in the scope of the publications it has access to.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like there is a problem with your security model. The internal search engine of the CMS will only return results to which the user has Read access. The fact that you can open them in Read Only mode shows that your user does in fact have read permissions on those components, so it is natural for the search engine to return them.

How have you restricted access to this content?